# How to delete rows without deleting dependent rows

Tags: sql-server

If there's already an answer to this, redirect me there. Google-ing this topic gave me many irrelevant results. I am new to SQL, doing project for college, and my problem is:
I'm making some kind of payroll system. Some of tables in my database are(translated to English): "DEDUCTIONS" - related to - "PAYMENTS" - related to - "EMPLOYEES". I have created a view "Salary reports", which combines data from these tables, so one can have insight on all previous salaries. BUT, when I try to execute this simple query:

```
DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@ID
```

I get the following error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint....

Now, I do realize that deleting rows from other tables together with the employee would solve the issue, but I really want to keep that data for the reports, even if I delete an employee. I thought to add another table to keep those reports, but I feel like that would lead to redundancy of data, convince me if I'm wrong. Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: the simple solution would be to have another column in the `Employees` table that stores the "state" of the employee instead of deleting it

Comment: The canonical solution to something like this is to not delete rows at all, but include a `Deleted BIT` pseudo-column that you set to `1` to indicate the row should no longer be considered in regular business processes (you can make a view out of this to avoid having to write `WHERE Deleted = 0` everywhere).

Comment: Another canonical solution (...) is to store for each employee an *employment start date* and *employment end date* (nullable), and change your queries as required to consider all employees, or only ones currently employed

Comment: Though the solution in the comments above will solve this problem, it may create other problems. When doing this the your foreign keys cannot help you anymore and you will have to modify all your select querys to filter out all `non active records`Which is lots of work. Moving the deleted records to a deleted table would be better imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is not the best idea, because (as you said) you have reporting dependencies that require the historical data.

While you can use `ALTER TABLE` to do this sort of thing and disable your foreign key checks:

`ALTER TABLE SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

Your real solution is likely to *add* data.   When you are dealing with historical issues and reporting, tearing out the data by disabling constraints is still going to break reporting when you delete a record.  Instead, it's typically better to use an "IsDeleted" boolean/bit column or similar to inactivate a record, and then just modify associated queries to check for "IsDeleted = 1" or "IsDeleted = false" or however you decide to flag it.  This maintains the data for historical reasons.

If DB file size has become an issue, and increasing storage space isn't a reasonable solution, your organization should review how long it wants to keep records, enroll in a backup policy that makes backups of the database on a schedule (i.e. tapes sent to Iron Mountain, cloud-based services, etc), store those backups for archival purposes, and just drop the records from the live tables which are old enough to have lost their meaning in daily practice.

Comment: This actually works like a charm, and as expected. I tried to find a way "How to hide a record", thinking there's some predefined way to do it, didn't think of this.... Simple solution that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the constraint in error to to not check against the constraint conditions, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```